# Android how to merge BIG picture from camera with another picture

Tags: android, bitmap, out-of-memory

I have 2 pictures:

1. a Picture that has just been taken from the camera (approximately 2MB)
2. a resource picture i want to add to the picture in section 1

i know how to do it technically but my problem is that when loading the picture that were taken in the camera to memory - i will always get `Out Of Memory` error unless i reduce the quality of the picture.

I don't want to change the quality of the picture, so is there a way to merge 2 pictures without changing the quality of the picture ?

Comment: It's not about a code - more about the process.